# Discord.js Set Interval function not activating. Need confirmation of cause

Tags: javascript, discord.js, web-hosting

I am currently having an issue with the setinterval function and was wondering if anyone could help. So oddly enough, it works for short intervals like 10 or 20 seconds but when I scale it to a day or half a day it fails to run. I'm on version 11.5.1 of discord.js

```
bot.setInterval(function(){
        var Holiday = new Date();
        var month = Holiday.getMonth()+1;
        var day = Holiday.getDate();
        var check = month+'/'+day;
        var greeting = "";

        for(var i = 0; i < Events.length; i++){

            if(check == Object.keys(Events[i]) && check != "12/25"){
              greeting = "Happy "+Object.values(Events[i]);
            }
            if(check == "12/25"){
                greeting = "Merry Christmas";
            }


        }
    for(var j = 0; j < c.length;j++){

    var channel = bot.channels.get(c[j]);

        if(greeting != ""){
        channel.sendMessage(greeting);


          }
      //channel.sendMessage('test');
    }

        }, 3600000,)
```

This is the function in the ready event. Events is a json file with an array of key value pairs. c is an array with channel ids. so in the json file I have a test date that when I ran for the current day it would work, but when I change the day to the next and then wait for that time to come, nothing happens but the time should have passed and the variables should have all been reset so any ideas? Also, I have the bot hosted on glitch sending itself ping requests as well as using uptime robot which has indicated there has not been a down for 60 hours. The only reason I could think of for the cause is that maybe glitch puts the bot to sleep for a split second and it causes the interval to constantly reset, but then that would mean the pings and uptime robot are having no effect. Also, if anyone has a clever work around I would be grateful. The best I could do was just have a command that does this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I've updated to the new version of the library things have changed. However, this was long ago and I was hosting on glitch at the time, and that ended up being the problem. Glitch will still put to sleep the bot even if you are pinging it with uptime robot as they prevent ping spam.

Answer (score 0):

maybe because you didn't break function at the end like this

```
      }
  //channel.sendMessage('test');
}

    }, 3600000);
```

and maybe that comma making the value act as an integer and more value going to be put in there.

Comment: Do you mean that the extra comma is an issue? It won't be a problem if OP uses Node.js version 8+, and would receive an error if used an older version.

Comment: Island, does your bot is online 24/7?